# File path autocomplete in Spyder?

Tags: python, r, rstudio, spyder

I am coming from RStudio and trying to adapt to Spyder.

Below a folder structure:

```
folder/
├─ scripts/
│  ├─ myscript.py
├─ raw_data/
│  ├─ data.csv
```

In RStudio, if I am in `folder/scripts/myscript.R` and want to read `folder/raw_data/data.csv` all I have to do is write `read.csv(` followed by `'../` then `tab` and the the options of choosing `scripts` or `raw_data` appear. I can navigate through it, and `tab` my way through to "data.csv" in half a second.

This is extremely time-saving because I do not always know what files are one or two folders upstream, or what their exact names are.

In Spyder, with the same folder structure, `pandas.read_csv(` followed by `'` (or `''`), then followed by `tab` does **not** work. This feature however exists, as seen below:

[image]

Note: I was pressing tab repeatedly when `''` was present to try. Using `'/'` sends me to my root directory, not my current working directory like RStudio does. Right now I have to go copy paste a full length path from the root to access my .csv files which is extremely time consuming.

Could you please kindly help me on this?
Many thanks in advance.